# SELECT COUNT() with LEFT JOIN, SUM() and HAVING()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d9f56/1/0

I keep getting more than a single row with the value `4` instead of the actual `COUNT()` I'm supposed to get, Which is `3`, And even if I increased the score to `6` or `7` the `COUNT` is till `4` with multiple rows instead of a single one.

I've added `SUM(b.score) AS score` to define it as a `variable` then i used `HAVING score > 0` at first to get the actual `COUNT`, How do I solve this problem and get a Single `COUNT` row with the actual count?

What i expect is **a single row containing the actual count of having score > 0, Which is 3**

What I do is get the `SUM()` of the `scores` for each `name`, Name `N1` with `id/nid = 1` Has a total score of `(10)`, When i change the `score > 0` to `score > 9` I'm supposed to get only 1 name with value `> 9`

```
N1(nid=1) (b.score SUM=10),
N2(nid=2) (b.score SUM=8),
N3(nid=3) (b.score SUM=6)
```

So
    `HAVING score > 0` is supposed to give me `COUNT(a.id) = 3`, `HAVING score > 9` is supposed to give me `COUNT(a.id) = 1`

Comment: Run `SELECT *
FROM names a
  LEFT JOIN scores b ON b.nid = a.id
` and manually create the groups to understand how it works.

Comment: can you edit your question with the expected result ? I'm quite confused

Comment: and grouping by something and applying an aggregate function on it at the same time doesn#t make sense

Comment: You're getting a 4 instead of 3, because the count you put there is counting how many scores there are for each name.id.

Comment: There are 4 rows for each ID why would you expect a 3 count?

Comment: Even after the edit this still makes no sense. When you change `score > 0` to `score > 9` the answer is 0 rows. Not one. You have *zero* rows with a score of `> 9`. If you meant to use `HAVING` you need to do `HAVING SUM(score) > 9`.

Comment: @JacobH How do I explain it, I select them by their `SUM()` for each `name`, I  updated it again now to explain it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far makes a good subquery for what you want:

```
SElECT COUNT(id) as idCount FROM (
  SELECT a.id, SUM(b.score) AS score FROM names a
  LEFT JOIN scores b ON b.nid = a.id
  GROUP BY a.id) ss
WHERE score> 9
```

You want the count of IDs which have a total score over your requirement, this query gives the expected results for your score levels.

The subquery gives:

```
+----+-------+
| id | score |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    10 |
|  2 |     8 |
|  3 |     6 |
+----+-------+
```

Then the query run on that simply counts the IDs where score meets your criteria in a where clause.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d9f56/142)

UPDATE -

The join in the subquery really does nothing, other than slow the execution down, based on the info you gave. You can remove the join, remove a step in the execution plan and speed the query up:

```
SElECT COUNT(id) as idCount FROM (
  SELECT nid as id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores
  GROUP BY nid) ss
WHERE score> 9
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d9f56/173)

Comment: Also the join is honestly redundant, `SELECT nid as id, SUM(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY nid` gives the same subquery result, since you never really make use of `names.name`

Comment: Also it seems to be a lot faster since it is possible to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`

Comment: `WHERE` on the external query performs almost identical to `HAVING` on the sub-query, because it is doing the same job. How did you decide that it is faster? The only time `WHERE` is faster is when used in the same query because it filters some results out before the `GOUP BY` does its job.

Comment: @RacilHilan I switched it in the fiddle and execution there took 1ms longer with `HAVING` over `WHERE`

Comment: This is not how you benchmark. If you run the exact same query twice, you will get different results. To benchmark appropriately, you'd need to run each query in a loop a few thousands times and then average the results and compare. Or run each of them on a big table with hundred thousands rows. You can do that if you really like to see for yourself, or you can take my word for it, there will be no meaningful difference. Or if you like, you can post a new question the performance difference, and we will answer it for you.

Comment: @RacilHilan I consistently see that difference running the query multiple times both ways, but I don't really care to argue the point.

Comment: I tried your query and mine 10 times each and both ran in 1ms-2ms. I did that just for fun, but again this proves nothing because it's not how benchmarking should be done, and you cannot benchmark in SQLFiddle because it depends on the website's load at any moment.

Answer (score 3):

Edit according to new info in question:

This explains why:

```
select a.id, COUNT(*), SUM(b.score) AS score
FROM names a
LEFT JOIN scores b ON b.nid = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING score > 0
```

You are grouping on a.id, but since you did not output it, it looked like duplicates.

This is what you need:

```
select COUNT(distinct a.id)
FROM names a
INNER JOIN scores b ON b.nid = a.id
WHERE score > 0
```

Comment: Although I agree with you 100%. This will return a 12 count. And the OP is asking for a count of 3. Which makes no sense. So have an upvote, since this explains the code, but it doesn't fix OP's [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... :) Edit: Your edit with the COUNT of Distinct I think may be what they want.

Comment: Thanks. The question was clarified now, so I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the question to calrify more, I'm not selecting them by the `b.score`, But `SUM(b.score) AS score` for each `nid`.

Answer (score 2):

Make your query a sub-query and select the count again:

```
SElECT COUNT(score)
FROM (SELECT SUM(b.score) AS score
      FROM names a
      LEFT JOIN scores b ON b.nid = a.id
      GROUP BY a.id
      HAVING score > 0) s
```

This will give you a single row with the value 3 as you requested. However, your query can be simplified because the join is not necessary:

```
SElECT COUNT(score)
FROM (SELECT SUM(score) AS score
      FROM scores
      GROUP BY nid
      HAVING score > 0) s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find out who has `score > 0` and then count, this could help:

```
select count(*) from 
    (select distinct nid 
     FROM scores
     where score > 0) as t
```

Comment: It would work, But It is not fit with the actual Query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query: (PS: I use select group in group, further tweaking probably needed to get optimal performance). 2 queries with different score in the where clause.

```
select  
    count(*), ab.id  
from 
    (select   
         a.id, sum(b.score) as score 
     from
         names a
     left join
         scores b on a.id = b.nid
     group by
         a.id
     having 
         score > 0) ab

select 
    count(*), ab.id  
from  
    (select
         a.id, sum(b.score) as score 
     from
         names a
     left join
         scores b on a.id = b.nid
     group by
         a.id
     having
         score > 9) ab
```

Comment: It seems that It will only with with Subquery after.